# Solve Logical Problem using contradiction rule and Truth Table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

There are three containers, one container has diamond in it, other containers are empty. Each
container has label as clue whatever is inside the containers. Those labels are:

---

- **Container#1:** The diamond is not present
- **Container #2:** The diamond is not present
- **Container #3:** The diamond is present in container#2

Only one statement is true and other are false. Which container has the diamond? Formalize this
problem into propositional statement and find a valid solution using truth table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the diamond can only be in one out of the two boxes, we can proceed with just one predicate
$$p=\mbox{Diamond is in box 1}$$
**Scenario 1**
$$\neg p\rightarrow \neg p\land p\equiv\mbox{false}$$
**Scenario 2**
$$p\rightarrow p\land p\equiv\mbox{true}$$
**Scenario 3**
$$\neg p\rightarrow p\land \neg p\equiv\mbox{false}$$
Solving it this way makes the solution very clear.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I think they're trying to discourage responses to low-effort questions.

Comment: @subrosar according to [the help section](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), downvotes on an answer mean that the answer isn't helpful. Perhaps the word helpful is a bit too vague.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities. Either the first statement is true, the second is true, or the third is true. If the first is true, then statement 2 and 3 are false, leading to a contradiction. If the third is true, then statement 1 and 2 are false, leading to a contradiction. Therefore statement 2 must be true, meaning statement 1 is false and the diamond is in container 1.